# Windows Phone 7- Set an Image source to a stream in memory

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, stream

Is it possible to set the source of an image in WP7 to a stream?  Normally I'd use BitmapImage to do this in Silverlight but I don't see that option in WP7.  Here's my code:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://10.1.1.1/image.jpg");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");    
request.BeginGetResponse(result =>
    {
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // myImage.Source = ??
    }, null);
```

The reason I ask is because I need to provide credentials to get the image - if there's another way to approach the problem I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, use this code:

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SetSource(stream);
myImage.Source = bi;
```

Comment: I tried doing the same on WriteableBitmap but failed. How do it do this on WriteableBitmap?

Answer (score 5):

In case WritableBitmap you can use:

```
        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(1000, 1000);
        Extensions.LoadJpeg(wbmp, stream);
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = wbmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<Image Name="Img" Stretch="UniformToFill" />

var bitImg= new BitmapImage();
bitImg.SetSource(stream);  // stream is Stream type
Img.Source = bitImg;
```